# Хранение состояния в coredata

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, coredata

Есть приложение типа блокнотика, на `tableView`. По кнопке я перехожу на след. вью контроллер, где есть параметры, которые я задаю: название, текст, фото и т.д. Все эти данные я храню в `CoreData`.

Хочу создать ещё один параметр: маленькое окно картинки, по которому я тапаю пальцем и оно меняет цвет на один из трех существующих(красный, зеленый, желтый), и, в зависимости от состояния кнопки, менялся цвет ячейки в `tableView`.

То есть, состояние картинки мне тоже надо хранить в `CoreData`, а я совсем не понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: а что вы уже пробовали? и что именно не получилось? точно так же, как вы сохраняете название и все остальное, сделайте int 0-2 который будет хранить цвет, или строку red, yellow, green.

Answer (score 2):

Как указал комментатор Max Mikheyenko, состояние вы можете хранить в кордате (определите для себя палитру цветов, например целое число от 0..(количество цветов).

Примерное видение:

- Модель (Класс) основана на Энтити из кордаты (уверен она у Вас уже есть)
- Кастомная ячейка, в которой лежит кнопка (если нужна именно кнопка) как счетчик, на которую юзер будет нажимать, и будет увеличиваться цвет до определенного диапазона, а, дойдя до конца, начнет отсчет с начального диапазона (вообще круговой счетчик). С помощью layer задать кнопке округлую форму или вешать картинки и т.д.
- в момент нажатия на кнопку в ячейке срабатывает экшн, в котором прописан метод апдейта этого объекта(полей) в самой кордате, ну и состояние цвета.
- каждому номеру состояния присвоен определенный UIColor.

(Все набросал на быструю руку. Правильность не гарантирую, но думаю, что направил в правильное русло. Начните проектирование на бумаге, нарисуйте переходы, где что лежит и т.д. Вам тогда будет проще ориентироваться)